# init.d service command not automatically redirecting to systemctl command

Tags: systemd, systemctl

On my machine, I get the following output:

```shellsession
$ sudo service my_service2 status
my_service2 running[  OK  ]
```

However, I expected to see this behavior as with another unit:

```shellsession
$ sudo service my_service1 status
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status my_service1.service
```

How can I get `my_service2` behavior to be the same as `my_service1` behavior?

Specifically I am interested in the redirect behavior of reissuing the command to systemctl automatically.

Note: know this is possible because the behavior that I am looking for exists on another machine that I have.

Comment: This question [seems familiar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77802459/init-d-service-command-not-automatically-redirecting-to-systemctl-command). It looks like `my_service2` is implemented as a legacy `init.d` service, while `my_service1` is actually a systemd unit. `init.d` style services are not managed with `systemctl`. If you want to manage `my_service2` using `systemctl`, write an appropriate service unit.